# Can I declare a context outside using() and still get Dispose() to be called?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, datacontext, using

I have a class `FooDataContext`, that implements Linq's DataContext, that have `Dispose()`..

```
public partial class FooDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext {...}
```

I know I should declare fooDataContext inside a `using(<here>){}`, so Dispose() is called for me, like this

```
public void Bar()
{
    using (var fooDataContext = new FooDataContext(ConnStr))
    { // some code
    }
}
```

But I don't know if this is just as good. Is it? What happen behind the scene?

```
public void Baz()
{
    var fooDataContext = new FooDataContext(ConnStr);
    using (fooDataContext)
    { // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: I should add, I would never use fooDataContext before or after using(). My focus was the Dispose() part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter will basically behave the same way, with one downside: you can still refer to `fooDataContext` *outside* the `using` statement, despite the fact that it's then disposed. That's rarely a good idea.

So yes, it's entirely legal to use the second snippet - but you should prefer the first version in almost all cases.

Comment: I would never use fooDataContext after using, by purpose. But yes mistakes happen and I should always keep it in using. But thanks, it's nice to know it's still get disposed even if it's declared before the using +1. - The reason I asked, beside knowing, is that the Baz() is in production right know, so I can't just change it. But I still wanted to know how critical the issue I ran into was.

Answer (score 2):

An exception might occur between the instanciation and the `using` especially if you add custom code. Calling the constructor within the using is safer. Moreover with the first solution you prevent working with a disposed context.

```
public void Baz() 
{ 
    var fooDataContext = new FooDataContext(ConnStr); 
    //Exception here -> fooDataContext not disposed
    using (fooDataContext) 
    { // some code 
    }
    //You can see fooDataContext here
}
```

If you really want to see the `fooDataContext` variable after the `using`, you can try this :

```
public void Baz() 
{ 
    var fooDataContext; 
    using (fooDataContext = new FooDataContext(ConnStr))
    { // some code 
    } 
    //You can see fooDataContext here
}
```